# How to use asyncio.semapahore in FastAPI?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, semaphore, httpx

I am building a FastAPI server for an image classification model. The API takes in image urls and downloads them concurrently using httpx. I want to limit the number of concurrent downloads across the server using asyncio.Semaphores. I tried creating a sempahore as a classifier attribute as I need it shared among all requests. But I get the error: `got Future <Future pending created at /usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py:424> attached to a different loop`.

Here is my code:

```py
 
# classifier.py

import asyncio
import httpx


class Classifier():
    def __init__(
        self,
        concurrency_limit,
    ) -> None:
        self.client = httpx.AsyncClient()
        self.semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(concurrency_limit)

    async def download_async(self, url):
        async with self.semaphore:
            response = await self.client.get(url)

        return await response.aread()

    async def run(
        self, image_urls
    ):
        image_list = await asyncio.gather(
            *[self.download_async(url) for i, url in enumerate(image_urls)]
        )

        # Infer Images
        pass



# api.py
from fastapi import FastAPI

server = FastAPI()

classifier = Classifier(concurrency_limit=5)

@server.post("/")
async def index(urls):
    results = await classifier.run(urls)
```

Answers online mention creating a semaphore within a running Event loop, but if I create it within `run()` a new semaphore is created for every request. i.e each request allows 5 downloads concurrently. How do I use the same semaphore across all requests?

Comment: I think you should try move your `classifier = Classifier(concurrency_limit=5)` into a `startup` event handler https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event  see also https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/lifespan.html#startup-receive-event

Comment: Yep. Just tried that a while ago seems to be working fine. Although I have to declare `classifier` as a global variable. Is there any way I could avoid using global variables?

Comment: it might be a use case for FastAPI's dependency injection https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/

Comment: Hey @Anentropic, any idea how to write offline test cases for the classifier? I'm not sure how to correctly mock httpx.get for the dependency.

Comment: try this https://github.com/lundberg/respx